# Pagination is not showing

Tags: laravel, pagination

I'm trying to get pagination into my view. I don't know where is the problem, the code doesn't show any errors.

**Here is my controller function**

```
public function apakskategorijas($id)
    {
        $apakskat = apakskategorijas::with('prece')->where('id',$id)->paginate(2);      
        return view ('kategorijas.apakskategorijas',compact('apakskat'));
    }
```

**View**

```
@section('content')

    @foreach($apakskat as $apk)
    @foreach($apk->prece as $prec)

    <div class="col-md-4 kat">
        <a href="{{ url('kategorija/apakskategorija/preces/'.$prec->id) }}">
            <div>
                <img src="{{ URL::to($prec->path) }}"> 
            </div>
            <div class="nos">
                <p>{{$prec->nosaukums}}</p>
            </div></a>    
            <div class="price-box-new discount">
                <div class="label">Cena</div>
                <div class="price">{{ $prec->cena }} €</div>                
            </div>
            <div><a href="" class="button btn-cart "><span>Ielikt grozā</span></a></div>      
    </div>

    @endforeach
    @endforeach

    <center>{{$apakskat->links()}}</center> <--pagination
    @endsection
```

**dd($apakskat)**

[image]

**UPDATE**

when i changed code in my controller to `$apakskat = apakskategorijas::paginate(1);` then it showed me pagination, but this doesn't work for me since i need to display items in each subcategory, with this code it just displays every item i have,it doesn't filter which subcategory is selected.

This is why i need this `$apakskat = apakskategorijas::with('prece')->where('id',$id)->paginate(1);` with is a function that i call which creates a relation between tables, so that it would display every item with its related subcategory.

Comment: Please put `@dd($apakskat)` into the view and show the results.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin edited post

Comment: I know it's will be weird but you can try to change $apakskat in to $apakskats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the behavior of paginator in current Laravel version. When you have just one page, pagination links are not displayed.

To test this, just change the code to something like this to get more pages:

```
$apakskat = apakskategorijas::paginate(1);
```

If you want to show the first page if there is only one page, you need to [customize pagination views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view). Just publish pagination views and remove this `@if/@endif` pair from the `default.blade.php` but keep the rest of the code as is:

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    ....
@endif
```

Comment: @Rhercb I've updated my answer. You need to customize pagination view (the `default.blade.php` one).

Comment: Yes, it now shows pagination. Only it shows that i have 1 page. Is there a particular way to change how many items it shows per page?

Comment: @Rhercb change `->paginate(2)` to whatever you want. For example, `->paginate(4)` will show 4 items per page.